# How to Manage the Decimals in the Columns in a Rendertable in Shiny (R)

Tags: r, shiny, decimal

I have my shiny application where I am working with very low values and I would need to display more than two decimals in my tables in the rendertables.

I have tried to set options(`digits=10`) at the beginning of the script, but it did not work.  I tried with

- `round()`
- `format()`
- with `digits=c()` inside the output rendertable....

Nothing works and I am starting to think that, maybe, shiny has a limit showing just two decimals in the rendertables.

Do anyone have an idea whether it is possible to fix this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of the behaviour you are describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `format(., digits = 10)` does work for me:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput('table')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable(
    data.frame(x = c("a", "b"),
               y = c(format(0.03245920421, digits = 10), 
                     format(0.01034101004, digits = 10)))
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```